# Openvpn bandwidth rate limit with the tun0

Tags: debian, limit, bandwidth, openvpn, rate

I need to set bandwidth (40 Mbps) per ip in my Openvpn server.
Even using the `tc/tcset`, The bandwidth has no change and is `10mbps`.
So the question is how to change it...
What I did before :

Modifying  `snd/rcv` `buff`, `tun-mtu`, `mssfix`, `fragment`.

Debian stretch + latest packages. 4 Gig of ram.

```
tcset tun0 --rate 40mbps --network 192.168.10.6/32 --change 
[INFO] tcconfig: clipping specified bandwidth rate limit with the tun0 maximum bandwidth rate
(40.0Mbps -> 10.0Mbps)
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved
A config in kernel - may be hard coded -
and

```
tc qdisc add dev tun0 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev tun0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbit ceil 1000mbit
```

At last 
Thanks to someone who read and pressed her/his finger and oh ! -1 ! 
Thank you your'e a hope in desert !

Comment: Please elaborate in detail I'm having same query like how to set limited bandwidth for each user

Comment: @Hanzala The answer uses a kernel feature. You can read more [here](https://lartc.org/)